# Level designing with Cocos2d and Box2d

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, game-physics

I want to learn how to make levels using cocos2d and box2d (for iOS).
I am talking about a 2d platformer such as Limbo or Braid or something like that. How can I design and build levels like this?

I have seen Level Helper for cocos2d but its not free and I don't think it makes physic objects for box2d.  How is this accomplished in real games?

How to make camera move with character and so on. Any starting points would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are excellent tutorials for 2d scrolling platform game

http://www.raywenderlich.com/15230/how-to-make-a-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-1

http://www.raywenderlich.com/15267/how-to-make-a-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-2

Comment: This tutorial looks almost like a pixel art game. And by the look of the TMXTiledMap it seems that I can only create square style ground. The tutorial creates its own engine as well. Can I use this tiled map for a nice smooth level for example Tiny Wings excluding the random hill generation? I want nice smooth hills and integration with box2d. It seems the internet is at lack of that type of knowledge :)